# Let $V$ be a $K[x]$ module with endomorphism $T$, then the ideal $(V)$ is non-zero.

Tags: linear-algebra

Whilst reading my linear algebra notes I came across the following theorem. I am wondering why the last statement that the $Ann(V)$ contains a non-zero polynomial of degree $\leq n^2$ is not $\leq n^n$.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $p_i$ is a monic polynomial of degree at most $n$.  For simplicity, write $p_i(x) = x^n$.  Then, we have that:
$$P(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n p_i(x) = \prod_{i =1}^n x^n = x^{\overbrace{n+n+\dots+n}^{n\text{ times}}} = x^{n\cdot n} = x^{n^2}$$
So, we have the degree of $P(x)$ is $n^2$.
This is because when we multiply two polynomials, their degrees add, not multiply.

Comment: Oops my mistake this is super obvious now.